# how to prevent duplicate random ints

Tags: java, arrays

```
for (int x = 0 ; x < chosenQ.length ; x++) 
{
    chosenQ [x] = r.nextInt (9);
    c.println (chosenQ [x]);
}
```

This generates 5 ints between 0 and 9. How do i make it so it will not have duplicate ints when generating it?

Comment: You tagged this question as 'javascript'... should be 'java'.

Comment: small set of possible values, and you want a significant amount of these values without repetition: create an Array of all possible values, shuffle it, and take the first n *(5)* values

Answer (score 1):

- Create an array with 10 elements from 0 to 9
- Shuffle the array
- Take the first five elements

In pseudo code

```
array = [0, 1, ..., 9]
array.shuffle.take(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to keep a record of which numbers were chosen already.

One way you can do that is by storing the values in a boolean array where all values are initialized to `false`. When a random value is generated, the element at that index is set to `true`. Then, for each generated number, you can simply check if the element at that index is `true` or `false`.

For example,

```
// array of booleans initialized to false
boolean[] array = new boolean[chosenQ.length]; 

for (int x = 0 ; x < chosenQ.length ; x++) 
{
       int i = r.nextInt(9); 
       // check if value was chosen already 
       while (array[i] == true)
           i = r.nextInt(9); 

       // set generated value's index in array to true
       array[i] = true; 

       chosenQ[x] = i;
       c.println(chosenQ[x]);
}
```

Comment: this is a pretty inefficient approach, and absolutely not suitable for bigger sets of values

Comment: For this to be a memory efficient approach, you should use a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) instead of a boolean array.